# Weight painting in a fully established material

Tags: texture-painting, normals

So today I am working on a landscape that I will eventually animate in 4K, therefore I want to create a lot of detail.

[image]

I want to start painting in some nice detail near the river ( highlighted in red ) first.

I have some simple river rock textures and some grass textures like below. [image]

So my question is:
 - Is there a simple way to paint several fully realized textures ( with colors and normals ) on to a singular plane?

Can't seem to figure it out and I have been at it all morning.

Thank you everyone!!!

Comment: Would substance painter be a possible solution ?

Comment: Your nodes are difficult to read. They can be bigger for easier reading.  The texture does not need to be so big.

Comment: Please show two textures or more ... small is fine. You can also use texture provided by Blender for testing .. not for final product

Comment: Do you know how to texture paint a gray scale image for your UV mapped mesh?

Comment: I am having my own problems with Blender.  It keeps crashing when I try to do anything

Comment: Sometimes weight painting means assigning weight to vertices of a mesh.  Perhaps factor painting for the mix shader node,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Consider a mix shader node in your shader nodes where you can change the contribution of each texture. A texture can determine the contribution pixel by pixel.  Two standard standard textures linked to Two BSDF shaders linked to a mixed shader.  The relative contributions are mixed in a ratio specified by a hand painted texture.  Image above.

[image]

Texture slot in Texture Paint. UV Map. You can paint the grayscale image in either area when set up correctly.  My machine is currently having problems. Final Render Seems accurate. You may need to save your image edits frequently.

[image]
A render. Checkerboard texture wrapped around torus and musgrave texture visible in areas determined by the manually paint grayscale image.

You can paint a gray scale image to hold the contribution from a texture information.  You can also paint with a stencil in texture painting.

Attempt to accomplish a simple case first ... base color first .. then the texture color ... the value connected for the contribution is a gray scaled painted with texture paint.  Make the texture and nodes first then your texture painting work will be realtime live ... assuming enough gpu cpu compute power.

Please inspect and improve.  Currently I cannot get interactive updates on my machine.  Perhaps someone will comment on that.

Comment: Hey Atomic! Thank you for responding. So I understand how to mix different textures under one material but I don't know how I would apply them with a brush in the areas that I want ...

Comment: Lets see your grayscale image.  You do not need to be perfect just accomplish proof of concept.

Comment: I am sure you are right but I just can't translate/understand what you mean it without images ... I will try again and  post some better pictures of my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Alright , so this is as close as I got for today... I just saw you gave an in depth answer so first I have to thank you for that and I will try the tomorrow or the next day and let you know how that works out.

So for this image I figured out a way to mix stencils to paint this plane , which is almost exactly what, the only thing I need to figure out is how to hook in 2 separate normal maps ...

Anyways I see what you are talking about ... I will have to give that a shot!

THANK YOU SO MUCH ATOMIC!!!
[image]