# How to merge the edges

Tags: texturing

With the Ant Landscape addon created the mountain and added a default plane and applied blenderkit addon water mater. How can i merge or make natural look to the mountain and water. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

**[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1msomMn9soDmKtTkb9-3D_d3X3swFo7Hy)**

Comment: Please show your work as a Blender screen capture.

Comment: I have no interest in opening your Blender File.  Others may have interest.

Answer (score 0):

Use a grey scale image as factor to a Mix Shader node to control transparency or displacement.

[Weight painting in a fully established material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167736/weight-painting-in-a-fully-established-material/167739#167739)

Comment: I tried maybe did not work me. Can i get detail explanation. File is attach. Thanks